# populate list inside table laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

hi i have this table in my view but the requirements is that i need only to display 9 columns but the database fields are more than 9. so what i did is that i made a dropdown button where it displays the 'flag' columns in my database here is how it looks
[image]

here you can see i already added the flags when you hover it would display the flags for a specific record. but the thing is that, the values displayed are just the same. here is my code

```
@foreach($myRep as $list)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $list->reportid }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->reportname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->filesize}}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->filetype}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class='dropdown-button btn defcolor' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Flags</a>
                    <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content dcont'>
                        <li>
                            VLR
                            @if($list->vlr == "true")
                                <i class="material-icons cGreen">check</i>
                            @elseif($list->vlr == "false")
                                <i class="material-icons cRed">close</i>
                            @endif
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            VOICE
                            @if($list->voiceservice == "true")
                                <i class="material-icons cGreen">check</i>
                            @elseif($list->voiceservice == "false")
                                <i class="material-icons cRed">close</i>
                            @endif
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            SMS
                            @if($list->smsservice == "true")
                                <i class="material-icons cGreen">check</i>
                            @elseif($list->smsservice == "false")
                                <i class="material-icons cRed">close</i>
                            @endif
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            DATA
                            @if($list->dataservice == "true")
                                <i class="material-icons cGreen">check</i>
                            @elseif($list->dataservice == "false")
                                <i class="material-icons cRed">close</i>
                            @endif
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            FINANCIALS
                            @if($list->financials == "true")
                                <i class="material-icons cGreen">check</i>
                            @elseif($list->financials == "false")
                                <i class="material-icons cRed">close</i>
                            @endif
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            DEVICES
                            @if($list->devices == "true")
                                <i class="material-icons cGreen">check</i>
                            @elseif($list->devices == "false")
                                <i class="material-icons cRed">close</i>
                            @endif
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $list->doc_class }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if($list->confidential == "true")
                        <i class="material-icons cGreen">check</i>
                    @elseif($list->confidential == "false")
                        <i class="material-icons cRed">close</i>
                    @endif
                </td>

                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $list->created_at)->format('M - d - Y') }}</td>

            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

any idea on what im doing wrong? thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your lists are being built correctly, but your javascript is not working properly and keeps showing the same list over and over again.

You need to make sure your elements are uniquely identified:

```
<a class='dropdown-button btn defcolor' href='#' data-activates='dropdown-{{ $list->reportid }}'>Flags</a>
    <ul id='dropdown-{{ $list->reportid }}' class='dropdown-content dcont'>
```

Now your javascript will know which list it needs to show.